# performance for xarg vs. python multiprocessing+subprocess

Tags: python, unix, multiprocessing, xargs

I have a question on the performance scalability with xargs. Currently I have a batch processing program written in python with multiprocessing and subprocess. Each process spawns an independent subprocess.popen() to execute an external command. Recently I realized that the whole process can be redone with xargs. However, I wonder whether it is a good idea to use xargs to process 10k+ files since I have never done something this scale with only commandline tools before. Given my test with small data sets, it is actually not a bad idea if all I am doing is batch running a bunch of commands, since it avoids many cycles of overhead imposed by python's modules, but I would like to learn more from anyone who may have more experience with xargs and python. More specifically, is there any buffer limit that I need to configure for xargs to consume a large number of inputs? Thanks.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

"If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses. Don't write short descriptions of the horses, post them on the Internet, and ask random strangers to guess which is faster!"

Comment: I'm guessing the cost of either `xargs` or `subprocess` will be so small that you won't notice the difference. Or, if there is a difference, it will be more about which one partitions the set of arguments best, not which one has the least overhead. But as Christian Temus says, why guess when you can actually know the answer?

Comment: i am not asking random strangers, but for people who may have the experience with similar problems. thanks for the time anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xargs` program will collect multiple arguments from standard input, and glue them together to make one long command line.  If there are many many many arguments, too long for one command line, then it will build and execute multiple command lines, as many as needed.

This means less overhead for starting up processes and shutting them down.  How much good this will do for you depends on how long your processes run.  If you are starting up some sort of CPU-intensive program that will run for half an hour, the startup time for the process will be inconsequential.  If you are starting up a program that runs quickly, but you are only running a small number of instances, again the savings will be inconsequential.  However, if your program is truly trivial and requires minimal runtime, maybe you will notice a difference.

From your problem description, it appears to be a good candidate for this.  10K things with relatively short processing for each.  `xargs` might speed things up for you.

However, in my experience, doing any nontrivial work in shell scripts brings the pain.  If you have any directory names or file names that can have a space in them, the slightest mistake in quoting your variables makes your script crash, so you need to obsessively test your script to make sure it will work for all possible inputs.  For this reason, I do my nontrivial system scripts in Python.

Therefore, if you already have your program working in Python, IMHO you would be crazy to try to rewrite it as a shell script.

Now, you can still use `xargs` if you want.  Just use `subprocess` to run `xargs` and pass all the arguments via standard input.  This gains all of the benefit and none of the pain.  You can use Python to stick a NUL byte `chr(0)` at the end of each argument, and then use `xargs --null`, and it will be robust with filenames that have spaces in them.

Alternatively you could use `' '.join()` to build your own very long command lines, but I don't see any reason to do that when you can just run `xargs` as described above.

Comment: yeah, i am already doing the subprocess + xargs method with one of the operations. The operation itself is very simple, cost less than 1 s. I guesss this isn't a how-to question, but in term of scale, I haven't found any doc on whether there is any input limit for xargs. It looks like it just wraps a loop around the input and able to execute commands in chunks. Does it depend on anything like a buffer that I would need to configure for it to consume a long list of input?

Comment: My understanding is that xargs just keeps consuming arguments from standard input and adding them to the command line until the line is bumping up against a limit or standard input is exhausted.  Once it hits the limit it runs the command and then starts building another command line to run.  There is an option to let you set the limit, but I think the built-in default one works pretty well.  So xargs can handle any number of input arguments, but may execute its command multiple times when that happens.  More info here: http://offbytwo.com/2011/06/26/things-you-didnt-know-about-xargs.html

Comment: yeah, i read that yesterday. So I am doing a find | xargs sort of operation, I have been a bit confused on whether I need -s or -L flag (char limit vs. line limit)

Comment: Well, I don't think you really need either -s or -L flag.  Just try it with the built-in default and see how it goes.  Unless the program you are calling with xargs has an unusual limitation on how long of a command line it can handle, you shouldn't need to worry about it.